# Logout issue while remove URL for browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application when I am login to the admin portal using default URL `www.demoadmin.com/default.aspx` and clicked logout button it gets logged out successfully.But when I removed `default.aspx` from the URLs such as `www.demoadmin.com` only and try to logout then it always remained on the same `page.Application` do not get logged out.I have used cookies for it.

Please find below code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="uxLogout" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Log Out" OnClick="uxLogout_Click" />
```

.cs code:-

```
protected void uxLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_cook != null) _cook.Logout();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Common.LogError("List", "uxLogout_Click",  ex); }
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx");
    }

   private Cookie _cook;
   public bool Logout()
    {
        _cookie.RemoveAll();
        _cookie.Abandon();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using asp.net session? If yes then use Session.Remove(). It will work.

Comment: @jitendra This we can't reproduce on local it occurs aftering deployment on IIS or any server.So,How we  can do it?